Doubts about geodesics equation derivation from Lagrange's equations
I want to derive the geodesic equation from a Lagrangian pov, so I consider a Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q})$ given only by the kinetic energy wrote as the quadratic form of the kinetic matrix $A(q)$, i.e (with sum over same indexes)
$$L=T=\frac{1}{2} \dot{q}\, A(q)\, q = \frac{1}{2} A_{ij}(q) \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j$$
then I compute the Lagrange eqs:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}^i}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q^i} = A_{ih}\ddot{q}^h+\frac{1}{2}\left(2\frac{\partial A_{ih}}{\partial q^j}-\frac{\partial A_{jh}}{\partial q^i} \right)\, \dot{q}^j\dot{q}^h=0$$
where I know that $A(q)$ is symmetric and positive definite, now if i multiply from the left by $A^{hi}$ i.e. $(h,i)$ element of the inverse of $A$, i should get to a form similar to the geodesics equation:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}^i}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q^i} = \ddot{q}^h+\frac{1}{2}A^{hi}\left(2\frac{\partial A_{ih}}{\partial q^j}-\frac{\partial A_{jh}}{\partial q^i} \right)\, \dot{q}^j\dot{q}^h=0$$
now I would like to symmetrize the terms inside the bracket, to end up with the Christoffel Symbols, and i understand i should do something like splitting the term in a symmetric and antisymmetric part, like this:
$$Q^k_{hj}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\left(Q^k_{hj}+Q^k_{jh}\right)}_{Symmetric}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\left(Q^k_{hj}-Q^k_{jh}\right)}_{AntiSymmetric}$$
From the Symmetric part I can recover actually the Christoffel Symbols, BUT how do I prove that the antisymmetric part is acutally equal to zero?

I think the Euler-Lagrange equations should be
$$\tag1
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}^i}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q^i}
=\frac12\Big\{\frac{d}{dt}(2A_{ij}\dot q^j)-\frac{\partial A_{k\ell}}{\partial q^i}\dot q^k\dot q^\ell\Big\}
=A_{ij}\,\ddot q^j+\underbrace{\dot A_{ij}\,\dot q^j-\frac12A_{k\ell,i}\,\dot q^k\dot q^\ell}_{(*)}=0\,
$$
where
I use the notation
$$\tag2
A_{k\ell,i}=\frac{\partial A_{k\ell}}{\partial q^i}\,.
$$
By the chain rule we also have
$$\tag3
\dot A_{ij}=A_{ij,k}\,\dot q^k\,.
$$
Since $A_{ij}$ is symmetric,
$$\tag4
A_{ij,k}\,\dot q^k\dot q^j~%\stackrel{i\leftrightarrow j}
=~\frac{A_{ij,k}+A_{ji,k}}2\dot q^k\dot q^j
~\stackrel{j\to \ell}=~\frac{A_{i\ell,k}+A_{\ell i,k}}{2}\dot q^k\dot q^\ell\,.
$$
Since $\dot q^k\dot q^\ell$ is symmetric in $k,\ell$ we can rename the indices
in the second term $\frac12 A_{\ell i,k}\dot q^k\dot q^l$ and obtain
$$\tag5
\frac{A_{i\ell,k}+A_{ki,\ell}}{2}\dot q^k\dot q^\ell\,.
$$
for the RHS of (4).
This leads to
$$\tag6
(*)=\frac{A_{i\ell,k}+A_{ki,\ell}-A_{k\ell,i}}2
$$
which is nothing else than the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma_{ik\ell}$ of the first kind.
Applying the inverse metric $A^{ji}$ to the RHS of (1)
and using $\Gamma^j_{k\ell}=A^{ji}\Gamma_{ik\ell}$ shows that (1) is equivalent to the geodesic equation
$$\tag7
0=\ddot q^j+\Gamma^j_{k\ell}\dot q^k\dot q^\ell\,.
$$

I don't fully understand the correction you made about the Lagrange eqs, I mean, they are the same as the ones I wrote but we used different indices and I already did the change in index to unite the two sums. Or am I missing something? By the way thanks for the answer! This morning I thought about this and I think I reached the answer in a different way, maybe I will post it later as an answer to see if it's correct!

Ok. Looks like our EL equations agree. Thanks for pointing it out.
